# Explanation for a piece of javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, web

I am a beginner in javascript and I am looking at the following piece of code.

```
  var type_select = '<select id="type_select" style="margin-bottom:0px;">';
  var i;
  var customer_group = <?php echo json_encode($customer_group);?>;
  for (i = 0; i < customer_group.length; ++i) {
      //console.log(customer_group[i].group_id);
      if (customer_group[i].group_name == table_column_1){
          type_select = type_select+'<option value='+customer_group[i].group_id+' selected>'+customer_group[i].group_name+'</option>';
      }else{
          type_select = type_select+'<option value='+customer_group[i].group_id+'>'+customer_group[i].group_name+'</option>';
      }
  }
  type_select = type_select+'</select>';
  //not allow to click header
  if ( col == 0 ) {
      return;
  }
```

Please help to give me some idea of what it might be doing. Maybe some direction. I am not sure if this code is enough,Please try your best to help me and explain to me as much as possible. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use the javascript debugger in your browser to trace through the code and examine variables. Then you can see for yourself what its doing

Comment: Oh ok . There is something called javascript debugger. Thank you - RiggsFolly

Comment: Anyway, how to use it and I am still confused.

Comment: Whats your favorite browser. Google `ie debugger` or `Firefox debugger` etc

Comment: google chrome and safari

Comment: Someone please help me. It is very important. Thank you.

Comment: Google `chrome debugger` and learn to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's building a select dropdown box with some options

```
<select id="type_select" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <option value="some-value">Some text</option>
    <option value="some-other-value">Some other text</option>
    <option value="yet-another-value" selected>More text this one is selected on load</option>
</select>
```

Looking at the snippet of code you posted, it then does absolutely nothing with it

Hope that helps

Comment: How can I use javascript to make a textbox with a label and get input and store it to a particular column in the database

Comment: best to ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
var type_select = '<select id="type_select" style="margin-bottom:0px;">';
var i;

// this part of code will be interpreted by PHP Engine, on client side you will find an JSON representation of
// "Customer_group", probably gotten from database, or file
var customer_group = <?php echo json_encode($customer_group);?>;

for (i = 0; i < customer_group.length; ++i) {
    // here, you are building a HTML string, this will be attached to DOM using
    // ex : document.getElementById('YOUR_DOM_ID').innerHTML = type_select;
    if (customer_group[i].group_name == table_column_1){
        type_select = type_select+'<option value='+customer_group[i].group_id+' selected>'+customer_group[i].group_name+'</option>';
    }else{
        type_select = type_select+'<option value='+customer_group[i].group_id+'>'+customer_group[i].group_name+'</option>';
    }
}
type_select = type_select+'</select>';
//not allow to click header
if ( col == 0 ) {
    return;
}
```